# what does buri mean?

Tags: words, meaning

In the haiku from Bashō,

> おもしろき
>
> 秋の朝寝や
>
> 亭主ぶり

The last line, 亭主ぶり, is translated as "kind host" by one source. Does ぶり actually mean "kind" in this context?

Comment: hi kuo,
thanks for filling in the whole haiku in kanji and hiragana. perhaps you can assist me with figuring out how to install such japanese writing symbols on my apple?

btw, your photo reminds me of crossing under the tracks leaving shibuya station.

clare

Comment: on 2nd thought....i will figure it out on my own. thanks anyway.

Comment: sorry I was so slow on my reply. If you have a macbook, go under system preferences, then keyboard. Once under keyboard, click on the tab "input sources". Hit the +, and find Japanese, and then select that. It works for romaji and kana (most people are fine with that), and comes with a great in-built dictionary when you type. If you have any questions just message me and I can help!

Answer (score 2):

Adjectives come before the noun, so "ぶり" could not mean "kind" in this context. Some other possible translations are:

- According to http://nihongo.j-talk.com/, "ぶり" translates to a species of butterfly.
- "-ぶり" is also a suffix meaning way, attitude, or manner, so "亭主ぶり" could mean "husband-like manner", or "host-like manner".